# Google App Engine, Jquery, load method

Tags: jquery, google-app-engine, load

Hey all, new to App Engine and jQuery so here goes:

I want to dynamically load content into a div using jQuery's load method on a click:

```
 $('#menu a').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var page = $(this).attr('href');
                $('#header').load(page);
        });

<div id="menu">
<ul>
  <li><a href="home.html" class="active">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="header">
</div>
```

If I'm currently at /home, using app engine, this routes me to /home/page instead of loading page into my `<div id="header">` and leaving me at /home.  The above code works without using app engine (meaning the content at page is dynamically loaded into my div and I stay at the URL /home).  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the jquery below the menu HTML, or (recommended) inside a `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: Another option that should work is to use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/), like this: `$('#menu a').live('click', function(event) {...});`

Comment: I've got $(document).read() and I tried the .live('click') but I'm still getting routed to /home/page...thanks for the suggestions though

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot.  But, here is more info: in my app engine python script I have one class meant simply to produce index.html.  index.html contains all the code mentioned above and I have separate files containing html fragments which are meant to be loaded into index.html on-click.  I have one entry in the webapp.WSGIapplication list which corresponds to index.html.  I have four handlers in my app.yaml: 1) /css 2)/images 3)/js 4)/dev (in that order and the last one is where my project lives).  Hope that helps and sorry I cannot upload a running version of the page.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are running the appengine server?

There's no way you can access your own filesystem through the server.

Comment: I'm running the whole thing using the google app engine launcher.

Comment: So, the home.html and news.html are just static files?